# How to include key exchange algorithms required to connect to router using OpenSSH client?

Tags: ssh, cryptography

With OpenSSH_8.9p1 for Windows, I'm trying to connect to a NuCom router NC-WR764TGV:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1
```

Output:

> Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.1 port 22: no matching key exchange method found.
> Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au

Thus I tried:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Output:

> Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.1 port 22: no matching host key type found.
> Their offer: ssh-rsa

Then:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.1 -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,+ssh-rsa
```

Output:

> Unsupported KEX algorithm "ssh-rsa"
> command-line line 0: Bad SSH2 KexAlgorithms '+ssh-rsa'.

With ssh on my linux clients I had identical results. How can I talk to this router?

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185). etc. Your question *might* fit on e.g. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) (please read the linked on-topic page first to make sure).

Comment: Thank you @Izzy

Comment: Best luck! I first thought about Unix&Linux, but I don't know if they accept Cygwin questions. Might be worth a look, too (remember there is always `/help/on-topic` on each SE site – and each SE site is accompanied by a "meta" site to seek clarification, where you can often find a `scope` tag to check with first).